# How to toggle master CSS file in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to toggle between two css files on user click event, how can I achieve this on next js?

Comment: why would you need to change the css file? If you want to change styles you are better off using styled-components

Answer (score 0):

This would dynamically change the styles for a

element based off of a variable. In this example I'll use a Boolean.

```
<p
            className={
              orangeStyles==true
                ? styles.boldOrange
                : styles.boldGreen
            }
          >
            Example Text
   </p>
```